# In MS Excel, trying to highlight rows for several conditions

Tags: excel

This is an excerpt of a 100,000+ row spreadsheet...

```
State   Tax     Employee    Employee Name       Time    Withholding Adjustment
OR      WC      3           Julie Bond          0.00    0.00        0.00
OR      WC-ER   3           Julie Bond          34.80   0.57        0.08
OR      WC      4           Brendan Burke       151.35  2.50        0.38
OR      WC-ER   4           Brendan Burke       151.35  2.50        0.38
OR      WC-ER   5           Dawn Higgins        6.25    0.10        0.01
OR      WC      7           Richard Towns       160.00  2.64        0.40
OR      WC-ER   7           Richard Towns       160.00  2.64        0.40
OR      WC      8           Richard Davis Jr    0.00    0.00        0.00
OR      WC-ER   8           Richard Davis Jr    146.71  2.42        0.37
OR      WC      9           Derek Sangston      181.75  3.00        0.46
OR      WC-ER   9           Derek Sangston      181.75  3.00        0.46
OR      WC      1           Rachel Wilkeson     72.00   1.19        0.18
OR      WC-ER   1           Rachel Wilkeson     72.00   1.19        0.18
OR      WC      1           John Ferrell        34.00   0.56        0.08
OR      WC      2           Tamara Foss         56.00   0.92        0.14
OR      WC-ER   2           Tamara Foss         56.00   0.92        0.14
OR      WC      3           Karen Fullman       41.00   0.68        0.11
OR      WC-ER   3           Karen Fullman       41.00   0.68        0.11
OR      WC      5           Anthony Seth        34.75   0.57        0.08
OR      WC-ER   5           Anthony Seth        34.75   0.57        0.08
OR      WC      6           Nancy Stuart        27.50   0.45        0.07
OR      WC-ER   6           Nancy Stuart        27.50   0.45        0.07
```

I need to do 2 things:

1. Find rows where EMPLOYEE NAME appears only once and highlight it.
2. Find rows where EMPLOYEE NAME appears twice but one of the ADJUSTMENT values = 0.00 and highlight a different color.

For this sample, only rows 6 and 15 would be highlighted for having met condition #1, and only rows 1 and 9 would be highlighted for having met condition 2.

I found a lot of tips for identifying duplicates, for highlighting specific values, for highlighting row differences, etc., but nothing, as far as I could tell, that would help with finding these conditions.

I would appreciate any help with this.  Thank you!

New Table with added column...

```
State   IID Tax Employee    Employee Name   Time    Withholding Adjustment
OR  12  WC  3   Julie Bond  0.00    0.00    0.00
OR  13  WC-ER   3   Julie Bond  34.80   0.57    0.08
OR      WC  4   Brendan Burke   151.35  2.50    0.38
OR      WC-ER   4   Brendan Burke   151.35  2.50    0.38
OR      WC-ER   5   Dawn Higgins    6.25    0.10    0.01
OR      WC  7   Richard Towns   160.00  2.64    0.40
OR      WC-ER   7   Richard Towns   160.00  2.64    0.40
OR  12  WC  8   Richard Davis Jr    0.00    0.00    0.00
OR  12  WC-ER   8   Richard Davis Jr    146.71  2.42    0.37
OR      WC  9   Derek Sangston  181.75  3.00    0.46
OR      WC-ER   9   Derek Sangston  181.75  3.00    0.46
OR      WC  1   Rachel Wilkeson 72.00   1.19    0.18
OR      WC-ER   1   Rachel Wilkeson 72.00   1.19    0.18
OR      WC  1   John Ferrell    34.00   0.56    0.08
OR      WC  2   Tamara Foss 56.00   0.92    0.14
OR      WC-ER   2   Tamara Foss 56.00   0.92    0.14
OR      WC  3   Karen Fullman   41.00   0.68    -10.00
OR      WC-ER   3   Karen Fullman   41.00   0.68    0.11
OR  13  WC  5   Richard Davis Jr    34.75   0.57    0.08
OR  13  WC-ER   5   Richard Davis Jr    34.75   0.57    0.08
OR      WC  6   Nancy Stuart    27.50   0.45    0.07
OR      WC-ER   6   Nancy Stuart    27.50   0.45    0.07
```

Comment: Thank you, Scott!  I was just trying to do just that.  ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two rules with formulas:

First condition:

```
=COUNTIF($D:$D,$D2)=1
```

Second Condition

```
=AND(COUNTIF($D:$D,$D2)=2,$G2=0)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Scott!  This is great.  Condition #1 works splendidly, but after applying Condition #2 to 100,000 rows, I realized that I need to highlight the pair of affected rows, not just the one with 0.00.

Condition #2 would need to highlight each row for JULIE BOND and RICHARD DAVIS JR.

Comment: change out the `$G2=0` to `COUNTIFS($G:$G,"=0",$D:$D,$D2)>0` @JimDeGeorge  If this worked please mark as correct as I answered your original question.

Comment: The "COUNTIFS($G:$G,"=0",$D:$D,$D2)>0" worked perfectly!  Thank you so much, Scott!!!

Comment: If you're out there, Scott... I found that with over 100,000 rows I was bound to encounter common Employee Name names. So, I inserted COLUMN B to the data and added it to the conditional formatting: 

=AND(COUNTIFS($E:$E,$E2,$B:$B,$B2)=2,COUNTIFS($H:$H,"=0",$E:‌​$E,$E2)>0)

So that one of the AND counts was when Column B and E = 2.  The problem is that it's ignoring the "=0" bit and just highlighting when B and E = 2.

I edited the main question with new columns...

Comment: Only the 1st 2 rows for RICHARD DAVIS should be highlighted because ADJ = 0. The 2nd set of rows for RICHARD DAVIS are highlighted and shouldn't be because neither ADJ value = 0.

1st 2 rows are correctly not highlighted because IID is different.

Comment: I tried several changes to the condition...

#1   =AND(COUNTIFS($E:$E,$E2,$B:$B,$B2)=2,COUNTIFS($H:$H,"=0",$E:$E,$E2)>0)

#2   =AND(COUNTIFS($E:$E,$E2,$B:$B,$B2)=2,COUNTIF($H:$H,"=0"),COUNTIF($E:$E,$E2)>0)

#3   =AND(COUNTIF($E:$E,$E2)=2,COUNTIF($B:$B,$B2)=2,COUNTIFS($H:$H,"=0",$E:$E,$E2)>0)

#4   =AND(COUNTIF($E:$E,$E2)=2,COUNTIF($B:$B,$B2)=2,COUNTIF($H:$H,"=0"),COUNTIF($E:$E,$E2)>0)

To no avail, but #1 and #2 produce the same results.  I'll keep plugging away.

Comment: I think I have a winner...

=AND(COUNTIFS($E:$E,$E2,$B:$B,$B2)=2,COUNTIFS($H:$H,"=0",$E:$E,$E2,$B:$B,$B2)>0)

Comment: On a small subset of the 100,000 rows this works fine and the column filter does as well.  Applying the revised conditional format formula to the whole 100,000 records worked, too, but clicking on the filter button is another thing.  It just hangs and hangs.  I guess this is "volatile"?

Comment: Took 20 minutes for the filter dropdown to appear.  I selected the filter color...hanging.